# Why use $item->getText() instead of $item->text?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm a PHP noob, when I read some joomla module's PHP files and try to learn, I come across this:

```
class RokSprocket_Item
{
    protected $text;
    public function setText($introtext)
    {
        $this->text = $introtext;
    }
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

My question is, since function `getText()` is just returning `$this->text` without anything else, why use it? It seems to me `$this->getText()` can be totally replaced with `$this->text`.

Comment: they are getter and setter methods, pretty standard.

Comment: it could be an accessor method

Comment: ..the whole point about getters/setters is to give some meaning to protected/private members like ->text.

Answer (score 6):

1. Because if you allow `$something = $object->property` by setting the property as public then you also allow `$object->property = $something`. This will bypass any sort of validation [or other] that you might have running during `$object->setProperty()`.
2. Because the data returned by the 'getter' method might not actually exist until the 'getter' is called, ie. it might be fetched from a database or other data store.
3. Because the data returned by the 'getter' method might not actually be represented by a standalone property, it could be contained in an array or another object.
4. Do you see where I'm going with this?

If *you* don't see any reason to set your class properties as private or protected or to create getters and setters, that's your call. However, there are endless reasons why they are good ideas.

edit: here's a quick example from some code I've been working with:

```
<?php
Class Registry {

private $vars = array();

public function __set($index, $value) {
    $this->vars[$index] = $value;
}

public function __isset($index) {
    return isset($this->vars[$index]);
}

public function __get($index) {
    if( isset($this->vars[$index]) ) {
        return $this->vars[$index];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Index $index not set.");
    }
}

}//-- end class Registry --
```

Comment: you would wanna check if its set before returning it with __get ?

Answer (score 2):

Thats a best practice in object oriented programming called encapsulation. As you se the var $text is prepended by the keyword protected that meens you cannot access it directly from outside the object. You have to use a getter and setter method. One advantage is if you deside you want to preform some action on the var everytime it is accessed. For instance validate when modified. You may add validation in the setter method and be shure the change takes effekt everywhere because the var isnt accessible in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

It is one part of **Object Oriented Programming** that is called **Data Encapsulation**. You wrap the private data in classes and not allow users to access your variables directly. You only give them the values that you return to them by **public methods**

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public $amount;

    function __construct($amount) {
       $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function execute() {
         //do some code using amount that is set in constructor
    }
}

$obj = new Foo(5);
$obj->amount = 99999;
$obj->execute();
```

Basically you are giving user a direct ability to modify your variable that will be used by execute function. Therefore you set getter and setter methods that do not allow users to modify variable directly.

Comment: You don't need to/probably shouldn't do calculations to a `public` `get` method that is returning a variable....

Comment: I just demonstrated an example why he does not want to make variable publicly accessible

Comment: Then you should focus on the validation of the `set` method, as the `get` method for a private variable shouldn't be doing calculations to it, as it would only exist if that variable needs to be accessed and you want validation on what it can be set to. (thus putting it in the `private` or `protected` scope)

Answer (score 1):

The `$text` property of the class is protected. This means that within client code (outside the class) you cannot access the value or you will get a error.

What you need to do is call its `publicly accessible` method `getText()` to return its value.